# Display currency symbol ($) in an asp.net textbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using asp.net textbox

I want to display the value entered by user in a proper currency format e.g. if user entered 10000 and I want it to be formatted like this: 10,000 $

How this could be achived via javascript without using ajaxtool kit?

Comment: Display where? As they are typing it? In another label? On post-back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this with javascript.  The following code will change the value as the user types:

javascript:

```
   function fnCurrencyOnly(o) {
        var sValue = o.value;
        var sKey = String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode);
        if (document.selection.createRange().text == sValue) {
            sValue = sKey;
        } else {
            sValue = sValue + sKey;
        }
        var re = new RegExp("^\\d+(?:\\.\\d{0,2})?$");
        if (!sValue.match(re))
            window.event.returnValue = false;
    }
```

html:

```
<div>
   <asp:textbox runat="Server" ID="text" onchange="fnCurrencyOnly(this);" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    function formatText(txt)
    { 
 txt.value = '$' + txt.value;

    }

<asp:textbox onchange="javascript:formatText(this);"/>
```

Comment: This however will not correctly format your text but instead just add a $ at the beginning.  If the amount is $4,000 then the textbox will read $4000 instead of $4,000 with the comma.  If you want the currency correctly formatted with commas you would need to use solution below.